# Two lines of text in custom drawable button cut off button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have the following linear layout which contains 4 buttons where the first button has two lines of text in it (the last 3 buttons are identical so I have omitted the last 2):

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_drawable"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="firstline\nsecondline"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                    android:paddingRight="6dp" />

                ...
```

However, the two lines of text cause the button to get cut off like this:

[image]

Above this linear layout is a text view and below it is another linear layout containing buttons.

What could be causing this?

**EDIT**:
Both increasing `layout_height` to `100dp` and using `wrap_content` give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Those two lines of text probably requires the button's height to be greater than `40dp`. Try increasing `layout_height` or set to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Both increasing `layout_height` to 100dp and using `wrap_content` give the same result.  Updating question with this.